# UWP Unhandled Exception when writing to serial

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port, windows-10, ntdll

I'm having an issue with writing to a serial device in UWP. My task for writing to the port looks like this:

```
    public async Task WriteAsync(byte[] stream)
    {
        if (stream.Length > 0 && serialDevice != null)
        {
            await writeSemaphore.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(serialDevice.OutputStream);

                dataWriter.WriteBytes(stream);

                await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                dataWriter.DetachStream();
                dataWriter = null;                    
            }
            finally
            {
                writeSemaphore.Release();
            }

        }
    }
```

The code works fine the first two times I call this function. The third time I get Unhandled Exception in ntdll.dll in the **await dataWriter.StoreAsync()** line.

The full exception I can see is:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCB3FCB2C0 (ntdll.dll) in xx.exe:
>   0xC000000D: An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059767/visual-studio-an-unhandled-win32-expcetion-occured-when-clicking-button-often) mentions a garbage collector closing an input stream, however I don't see why would it happen in my code. Any help on getting to the bottom of this issue would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What language is this? This is tagged as "C".

Comment: It's C#. Just fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the solution to my problem was in another piece of code. I had a function reading the bytes like this:

```
        private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

        uint ReadBufferLength = 1024;

        // If task cancellation was requested, comply
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // Set InputStreamOptions to complete the asynchronous read operation when one or more bytes is available
        dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

        using (var childCancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken))
        {
            // Create a task object to wait for data on the serialPort.InputStream
            loadAsyncTask = dataReader.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(childCancellationTokenSource.Token);

            // Launch the task and wait
            UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                byte[] vals = new byte[3]; //TODO:adjust size
                dataReader.ReadBytes(vals);
                //status.Text = "bytes read successfully!";
            }
        }
    }
```

Specifically the problem was in the following two lines:

```
byte[] vals = new byte[3]; //TODO:adjust size
dataReader.ReadBytes(vals);
```

As soon as I set the size of the vals array to bytesRead value the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would not have to set `dataWriter` to null, because the GC will know that an object will not be used anymore.

You'd better call `dataWriter.Dispose()` method like many UWP samples.

For example: [SocketActivityStreamSocket](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket/cs/Server/Scenario1_Send.xaml.cs#L75)

Please read [IDisposable.Dispose Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) document for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, before I had the dataWriter wrapped in a using statement, however the problem was still there. In the end I think I managed to fix the problem although it was not where I was initially looking for it.